# WCF strange serialization of ReadOnlyDictionary

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I'm using WCF service reference (wsdl is generated at client side) which exposes an API function with an object [DataContract] which contains a [DataMember] Dictionary<string,DateTime> type. The object looks the same in both the client and the server and it is being used in many places today both at the client and at the server sides.

I wanted to make the object immutable and therefore - changed all its value type fields to have a private setter and the dictionary to the type ReadOnlyDictionary<string,DateTime>. At the server side all is fine - it makes sure no one can change the dictionary, but when I updated the service reference from the client, it has a strange type generated - this is how it looks in the reference.cs:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public SampleClient.RateDataService.ReadOnlyDictionaryOfstringdateTime Timestamps {
    get {
        return this.TimestampsField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.TimestampsField, value) != true)) {
            this.TimestampsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Timestamps");
        }
    }
}
```

So in the client side it is actually a strange object of type "ReadOnlyDictionaryOfstringdateTime" which contains a member called "m_dictionary" which is of type Dictionary<string,DateTime> and so, this field isn't immutable anymore. Why won't WCF use the same type at the client side? Is there a way to make it serialize into ReadOnlyDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

To explain this, we need to go through client side code creation using WCF. This is not a magic operation but it happens through steps.

When you add a reference to a WCF (or any other type of SOAP service), you are effectively downloading a WSDL file and the autogenerated code adheres to that file. [WSDL@w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp)

> WSDL stands for Web Services Description Language
>
> WSDL is used to describe web services
>
> WSDL is written in XML
>
> WSDL is a W3C recommendation from 26. June 2007

The intricacies of the WSDL and client code creation are well explained [here](http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,ff5fab81-affb-4b2b-aa67-c80bdfc86cbd.aspx)

> Because using System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary probably means you know there is no guarantee that client side representation will be possible if you are using an alternative platform. **There is no way to meaningfully convey the semantics of a .NET dictionary class using WSDL/XSD.**

Since your dictionary is just a "simple" XML translation, there is really no meaningfull way to pass the information that it is readonly to the client. There is also really no reason for the client to make it readonly, as it is just for serialization reasons. When the value will get to the server side, it will be readonly.

Comment: the client side is a consumer which receives these objects using a callback (this is a duplex communication), so i would want this dictionary to be read only in both sides to prevent any changes to it